# How to use baseUrl for absolute import statements in a library?

Tags: angular, tsconfig, angular-library

I have a library with a workspace containing two projects, one for the library itself and one for a test application.

```
├── projects
    ├── midi-app
    └── midi-lib
```

In the workspace `tsconfig.json` file I configured the `baseUrl` property:

```
"baseUrl": "./projects/midi-lib/src"
```

For the record, in this same file there are also some `paths` mappings:

```
"paths": {
  "midi-lib": [
    "dist/midi-lib"
  ],
  "midi-lib/*": [
    "dist/midi-lib/*"
  ],
  "@angular/*": [
    "./node_modules/@angular/*"
  ]
}
```

There is also a `projects/midi-lib/tsconfig.lib.json` file which extends on the above `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
```

but it contains no such `baseUrl` nor `paths` properties.

The build command of the library sub project is successful:

```
$ ng build midi-lib --watch
Building Angular Package
Building entry point 'midi-lib'
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
Bundling to FESM2015
Bundling to FESM5
Bundling to UMD
No name was provided for external module 'lib/service' in output.globals – guessing 'service'
No name was provided for external module 'lib/store' in output.globals – guessing 'store'
Minifying UMD bundle
WARN: Dropping duplicated definition of variable B [0:71,24]
WARN: Dropping duplicated definition of variable J [0:177,24]
Copying declaration files
Writing package metadata
Removing scripts section in package.json as it's considered a potential security vulnerability.
Built midi-lib
Built Angular Package!
 - from: /home/stephane/dev/js/projects/angular/midi-lib/projects/midi-lib
 - to:   /home/stephane/dev/js/projects/angular/midi-lib/dist/midi-lib
```

I have a `projects/midi-lib/src/lib/service/index.ts` file which contains:

```
export { MidiService } from 'lib/service/midi.service';
export { KeyboardService } from 'lib/service/keyboard.service';
export { SynthService } from 'lib/service/synth.service';
export { CommonService } from 'lib/service/common.service';
export { GeneratorService } from 'lib/service/generator.service';
export { MelodyService } from 'lib/service/melody.service';
export { ParseService } from 'lib/service/parse.service';
export { SheetService } from 'lib/service/sheet.service';
```

and allows such import statement:

```
import { SynthService } from 'lib/service';
```

I also have a `projects/midi-lib/src/lib/index.ts` file which contains:

```
export { Device } from 'lib/model';
export { MidiService } from 'lib/service';
export { DeviceStore, SoundtrackStore } from 'lib/store';
```

but is not being used yet, or so it seems to me.

I'm trying to use this library with the test application but its build command `ng serve` fails with the error:

```
$ ng serve
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Date: 2019-08-17T08:02:39.883Z
Hash: c6ef855b8b8907504425
Time: 69624ms
chunk {es2015-polyfills} es2015-polyfills.js, es2015-polyfills.js.map (es2015-polyfills) 323 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 37.9 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 254 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 17 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 4.45 MB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in ../midi-lib/src/lib/model/index.ts
Module build failed (from /home/stephane/dev/js/projects/angular/midi-lib/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
Error: /home/stephane/dev/js/projects/angular/midi-lib/projects/midi-lib/src/lib/model/index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
```

Before trying to simply use the `baseUrl` property for absolute import statements, I tried using the `paths` property, but I [failed miserably](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56949487/958373).

As a side note, my VSCode doesn't show any error.

I'm under version:

```
Angular CLI: 7.3.9
Node: 10.15.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 8.1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Base url is configuration for whole application not for some external libraries you can use base url like this `./` or `src` so in your case if you need additional scripts or js files go to `angular.json` find `architect -> build -> scripts` and add those file path to `scripts` array so when angular start or build will now from where to load and access those files.