# Develop Angular library and test in demo app without change import

Tags: angular, import, build, angular-library, angularbuild

I everyone, I have an Angular project structured like following

```
├── projects
│    ├── lib-1
│    ├── lib-2
│    ├── lib-wrapper
│    .
│    .
│
└── src
     ├── app
     ├── assets
     .
     .
```

in particular I not only develop library but also the app that incorporate them.
So I have to develop library and test them in my app "runtime" without build them for every time, then I import my libraries in my modules app using the ugly `import { a } from "../../../../lib-1/public-api.ts"` import statements and when I have to build libraries and also app I have to change all import in the "consumer" form `import { a } from "lib-1"`.

Notice that  `lib-wrapper` imports `lib-1` and `lib-2` and then I import lib-wrapper in my app in the same way (runtime import when develop and compile import when build).

Since I have too much libraries and too much import in my app, did anyone know if there is a method to import in an absolute way my libraries in such a way that when I use `ng serve` I link directly to my lib and I can test it runtime and when I use `ng build` the import link to the installed library?

Notice that I cannot use only production configuration `fileReplacements` (I can use it to change the import in the src/app but not in library since libraries not support this option. So the question is mainly for the libraries.

I found something useful here [questions 56949487](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949487/how-to-have-absolute-import-paths-in-a-library-project) but I didn't understand well how to use that informations in my use case.

Comment: tsconfig.json file:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "lib-1": ["projects/lib-1/src/public-api.ts"],
      "lib-2": ["projects/lib-2/src/public-api.ts"],
      "lib-wrapper": ["projects/lib-wrapper/src/public-api.ts"]
    }
  }
}

Comment: With this configuration, you can use the following imports in your application and libraries:

import { a } from "lib-1";
import { b } from "lib-2";
import { c } from "lib-wrapper";
This is will work in both runtime and build time.

Comment: In this way my app import the libraries like they are installed and if I develop on library I have to build and reinstall it to see changes.

Comment: My previous comment is wrong, with these paths the imports link to the project folder correctly but when I run the demo application it needs all libraries installed and the app run the installed libraries despite the import links to the projects file